# PHP See If All Values In Array Contain String

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to see if an array contains a specific set of strings. In my specific situation, I have an array that contains customer addresses. I am trying to see if every address is a PO Box or not. I want to print an error message if all of their addresses are PO Boxes.

This is what I currently have.

```
public function checkPhysicalAddressOnFile(){
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    foreach ($customer->getAddress() as $address) {
        if stripos($address, '[p.o. box|p.o box|po box|po. box|pobox|post office box]') == false {
            return false
```

Comment: I marked it as the best answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would approach it:

```
public function checkPhysicalAddressOnFile(){
    $addresses = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getAddresses();

    foreach($addresses AS $address) {
        if(!preg_match("/p\.o\. box|p\.o box|po box|po\. box|pobox|post office box/i", $address)) {
            // We found an address that is NOT a PO Box!
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Apparently all addresses were PO Box addresses, or else we wouldn't be here.
    return false;
}
```

Your code was pretty close to working already, you mainly just needed the `preg_match` function to check against a regex pattern.

---

Here's a more terse option:

```
public function checkPhysicalAddressOnFile() {
    return (bool) count(array_filter(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getAddresses(), function($address) {
        return !preg_match("/p\.o\. box|p\.o box|po box|po\. box|pobox|post office box/i", $address);
    }));
}
```

See here for an example: https://3v4l.org/JQQpA